# CakePHP 3.x Validator refuses to take correct data

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to validate a POST to create a new user, Cake is refusing to accept the given data.

The Validator is set up in the following way:

```
    $validator
        ->requirePresence('first_name', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('first_name');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('last_name', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('last_name');

    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('email');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('title', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('title');
```

Even tho I give it all the data it needs to succed, in the right format, right data type, when I debug using

```
    $x = $employee->errors();
    if ($x) {
        debug($employee);
        debug($x);
    }
```

it still has errors with the fields mentioned above:

```
'first_name' => [
    '_required' => 'This field is required'
],
'last_name' => [
    '_required' => 'This field is required'
],
'email' => [
    '_required' => 'This field is required'
],
'title' => [
    '_required' => 'This field is required'
]
```

I didn't expect to have that problem with Cakes Validator, why does it refuse this? Also I don't know to how to debug deeper into the problem, since there's a lot of automagic happening in the Validator.

The error occures no matter if the fields are filled iwth correct data or not any at all - I couldn't find anybody on SO or somewhere else to debug this problem, so I'm asking here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take time and look at User Entity. Check accessible array list.

Comment: What does `debug($employee)` output? Are the fields there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error:

employee is an object and the validator didn't look into the object, but looked for the fields on the object level.

I solved it by shifting the scope into the object - resolved it :)

Beginner mistake I guess, happy to have found it.

Thanks for help!